# How to use "But" properly

Tags: grammar

Which of these two sentence form is more accurate and why:

1. Ramiro is anything but professional.
2. Ramiro is anything but not professional.

These both sentences conveys the same message about Ramiro being anything except professional. But which sentence should be used. 
I would really feel grateful if one explains the answer.

Ps. 
Hi, English is not my native language and this is my first question here so please be kind. 
Thanks. ✌

Comment: Hi Rees, welcome to EL&U! I think you might get a better answer for this question on our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). You could ask it there directly, or we could try and get it moved for you. If you post it there I'll give it a good answer for you! :-) Just so you know, your two sentences mean opposite things!

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound rather stupid but why I can't get this question answered here instead? It's just a small clarification is all I need. Thank you very much. 

Comment: This is designed as a site for linguists and etymologists. It's designed to be a repository of questions that linguists, etymologists and  serious English language enthusiasts can use a bit like an encyclopedia. So they monitor the questions to check if they are a good fit for this site, or would be better on another one. ... (cont)

Comment: ... They are likely to close your question at the moment, because it isn't really an English Linguistics question :-) It's still a good question (which is why I upvoted it). But it will be much more helpful for future users if it is on ELL!! The people who need to know this information will be able to find it

Comment: Okay, thanks and sorry for my ignorance. I'll move this question. Thanks again 

Comment: Cool, I'll write you a good answer (I hope!). 

Comment: "Ramiro is anything but not professional" is not quite idiomatic, but generally would be read as "... anything but unprofessional" and hence "very professional".

Comment: Those two sentences mean opposite things..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both grammatical, but they mean different things. And there are other differences.

*Anything but `X`* is an idiom, and *but* in this idiom is a negative. So,

- *anything **but** professional* means 'definitely **not** professional'.

If you add another negative in the *`X`* element, the usual double negative confusion results

- *anything but not professional* means 'definitely not not professional'

which is hard to decode, if not ungrammatical. The `X` element can itself be a negative, however,

- *anything but unprofessional* means 'definitely not unprofessional'

provided the term can be negated, like *unprofessional*. However, *anything but unprofessional*  does not mean the same thing as *anything but professional*.

Comment: Similar remarks hold for _nothing_ instead of _anything_, and _except_ instead of _but_; i.e,  _Nothing but `X`, Anything except `X`,_ and _Anything except `X`_ all work the same way as _Anything but `X`_.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Ramiro is anything but professional is the correct way.
It is not really a question of grammar but rather of an expression of how we say it.

Ramiro is anything but not professional---when I hear that I understand what you want to say,  but it is not as clear.

Comment: -1 As mentioned in the other answer & in the comments, the 2 versions are NOT the same. Hence your comment that the second version "is not as clear" is plain wrong.